# how to access multiple json files using dataframe from S3

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using apapche spark. I want to access multiple json files from spark on date basis. How can i pick multiple files i.e. i want to provide range that files ending with 1034.json up to files ending with 1434.json. I am trying this.

```
DataFrame df = sql.read().json("s3://..../..../.....-.....[1034*-1434*]");
```

But i am getting the following error

```
   at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1924)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.range(Pattern.java:2594)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Pattern.java:2507)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2030)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1964)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1665)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1337)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1022)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.GlobPattern.set(GlobPattern.java:156)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.GlobPattern.<init>(GlobPattern.java:42)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.GlobFilter.init(GlobFilter.java:67)
```

Please specify a way out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read something like this.

```
sqlContext.read().json("s3n://bucket/filepath/*.json")
```

Also, you can use `wildcards` in the file path.

**For example:**

```
sqlContext.read().json("s3n://*/*/*-*[1034*-1434*]")
```

Comment: but how can i provide range in this as specified in the problem. files within a specific range

Comment: @Hitesh Goyal: what do you mean by specific range?

Comment: @HiteshGoyal: Spark file path supports wildcards.. whats your file path structure?

Comment: By specific range , i mean that if my json file name is like (s3://bucket_name/201611091207.json). Now consider the last 4 digits of this file and upnext file name is (s3://bucket_name/201611091210.json). so if i need to provide a range for last 4 digits so that i am able to fetch the json files existing in between this range. @Shankar

Comment: Can you point to a specification of these wildcards?

Comment: is it possible to use logical operators? For example you have folders by year: 2018,2019,2020. I just want 2019 onward.